# Handling stdin and stdout of subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

i want to write a Python script that creates a subprocess, reads from the stdout and writes to stdin. What is written to stdin should depend on whats been read from stdout.

I've tried pretty much everything i could find about subprocess.Popen, but nothing worked out.

Basically, i want to write a script that makes the following c-code print "success":

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stlib.h>
int main()
{
    int var, inp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var = rand();
        printf("Please type %d:\n", var); //random var. is printed
        scanf("%d", &inp);                //inp == var?

        if (inp != var) {
            printf("you failed miserably\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm failing at reading from stdout while still keeping the subprocess alive. The task seems so simple, but I can't find a simple solution.

Python code that i would expect to work:

```py
from subprocess import *
def getNum(s):  # "Please type 1234567:\t" -> "1234567"
    return "".join([t for t in s if t.isdigit()])

p = Popen("./io", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE) #io is the binary obtained from above c code
for i in range(100):
    out = p.stdout.readline() #script deadlocks here
    print( out )
    inp = getNum(out)+"\n"#convert out into desired inp
    p.stdin.write(inp)
print (p.communicate()[0]) #kill p and get last output
```

This approach might be a little naive, but i also don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Please also share your python code. That C code is not complete: can you give us a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's also not clear how the python code would run: from what I see, if you don't guess the random input, your program will exit.

Comment: I figured that there is no way readline() could work if i didn't start a new line, so i replaced the `'\t'` with `'\n'` in the c code, but the python script still deadlocks.

Comment: I think the problem is on the C side and is due to `stdout` buffering. One quick fix is to add a `fflush(stdout);` in between the `printf` and the `scanf`, this way your python script will have something from `stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

The python program gets stuck waiting to receive something from `stdout`. This can be due to `stdout` buffering. There are probably a few ways to change this behavior, but one quick way to test this out is to change the C executable to force a `fflush` right after it prints out the randomly generated number. The C code would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int var, inp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var = rand();
        printf("Please type %d:\n", var); //random var. is printed

        // ADDED EXPLICIT stdout flush
        fflush(stdout);

        scanf("%d", &inp);                //inp == var?

        if (inp != var) {
            printf("you failed miserably\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("success\n");
    return 0;
}
```

With that change, the original python script is able to drive the whole interaction.